# Pushing 2 variables into array with 1 key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, path, key

I am trying to push 2 variables into an array but I want that the key is the same.

The code below is a search function through a folder full of files.
In the foreach, I'm doing a check whether the name or a part of the name matches the search term. If there are results, I put the filename and the filepath in the array.

```
protected function search()
    {

        $keyword = $this->strKeyword;

        $foundResults = array();

        $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(TL_ROOT."/tl_files/");
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator,
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($iterator as $splFile) {
            if ($splFile->getBaseName() == $keyword) {
                array_push($foundResults, $splFile->getBaseName(), $splFile->getPathName());
            }
            elseif(stripos($splFile->getBaseName(), $keyword) >= 3){
                array_push($foundResults, $splFile->getBaseName(), $splFile->getPathName());
            }
        }

        return $foundResults;
    }
```

When I run the code it gives back the following:

```
[0] => FileName Output 1
[1] => FilePath Output 1
[2] => FileName Output 2
[3] => FilePath Output 2
```

As you can see , he set a new key for File name and File Path

But what I want is this:

```
[0] => Example
        (
            [fileName] => logo.png
            [pathName] => /tes/blalabaa/ddddd/logo.png
        )
```

I hope it's a bit clear, and someone can help me.

Greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the values you can push an array containing the key-value-pairs:

```
array_push($foundResults,
    array(
        'fileName' => $splFile->getBaseName(),
        'filePath' => $splFile->getPathName()
    )
);
```

Comment: Lashane's solution with $foundResults[] does the same, but it is a little cleaner to read and more php style.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I used this code and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
$foundResults[] = array(
    'fileName' => $splFile->getBaseName(),
    'pathName' => $splFile->getPathName());
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was the solution I was looking for +1 :)